# PHP Grid type Array get row or column

Tags: php, arrays, grid, row

This **may** sound like a silly question and I'm not thinking hard enough,

Or its harder than i think...

Say i have a array of numbers like:

```
$table = array(
'5','2','1','4','4','4',
'1','2','4','2','1','1',
'3','4','3','1','4','4',
'1','4','2','S','4','4',
'1','2','4','2','1','1',
'5','2','6','4','8','1'
);
```

S = where I want to get either the row or column based on where "S" is.

I know i can get where S is.

by doing:

```
$start = array_search('S', $table);
```

The ''grid'' this array is based on,The S can can be anywhere.

And the grid itself can be different sizes length and width.

How would i go about getting the whole row or column.?

(IE:S is in column 3 : 4,2,1,S,2,4)

(IE:S is in row 3    : 1,4,2,S,4,4)

Just a hint in the right direction would be helpful, Don't need to go all out for me.

Or a idea on how to approach this.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I guess you have the width you want to use stored somewhere! (And you don't want to use 2-dimensional arrays, check the other answer if you don't care, a 2-dimensional array makes a lot more sense in this case).

If you want to get the line, use `$start` which is the position of S in the array and divide it by the width. Then you need to round down or up (depends on if you are starting to count at 0 or 1)

For column you need to do something similar, use `$start % $width` here. (add 1 if you start counting at 1).

Comment: I'm sure, I can get the 'grid of numbers' into a 2d array. but thanks, I will also try play with this also. see if i can get It like this. I'm still in the process of learning, fun times, keeps me busy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint:

```
$table[] = array();
$table[][0] = array(5,2,1,4,5);
$table[][1] = array(1,5,2,3,3);
$table[][2] = array(1,2,'s',4,5);
```

You will need an array of arrays to have an x/y search.

Your x is the nth element in the outer array.

Your y is the nth element in the inner array.

Comment: @bsdnoobz Make's sense, Thanks. I'm now going to try out some of these. to see if i can get the results I'm wishing for. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can search your string like 's' in array and find column and row of that :

```
$cols=5;     // your columns count
$row=1;
$i=1;

$array = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','s','9');  
foreach($array as $value)  
{  

  if($value=='s')
   {
     echo 'Column : '.$i .' || Row : ' .$row ;
   }
  if($i==$cols)  
   {  
      $i=0;
      $row++;
   }  
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: Ok this has helped me a lot, Thank you. Not 100% what I was looking for but none the less is on the perfectly right track!